# how to add value to value1[i]->value2?

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

This is for C language and on ubuntu.

I am currently stuck at this problem:

```
struct dretva {
    int id;
    int p;  
    int prio; 
    int rasp; 
};

struct dretva *P[5];

int nove[6][5] =
{
    { 1,  3, 5, 3, 1 },
    { 3,  5, 6, 5, 1 },
    { 7,  2, 3, 5, 0 },
    { 12, 1, 5, 3, 0 },
    { 20, 6, 3, 6, 1 },
    { 20, 7, 4, 7, 1 },
};
```

How do i add value to P?
I am doing it like this:

```
P[0]->id=nove[0][2];
```

but when i write it with printf like so:

```
printf("%d",P[0]->id);
```

it says Segmention fault (Core dump) which means that P[0]->id has no value. How? How do I add value to P[0]->id?

Thank you.

Comment: You forgot to allocate memory. See Coderredoc's answer.

Comment: Do you need P to be an array of pointers? Won't `struct dretva P[5]` be enough?

Answer (score 3):

After you allocate memory to those struct pointers you can add the way you are adding or mentioned in question.

In case you use pointers you need to give it some memory to which you can make it point to...

Right now you get error because of that..(no memory allocated)
Add this line and initiate them with values.

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
  P[i]=malloc(sizeof(struct dretva));
```

Easy way as pointed by  4386427

```
struct dretva *P = malloc(5 * sizeof(struct drevta)); 
if (P == NULL) {
    exit(1);
}
```

Its good practice to free the memory later.

Comment: It says dretva is undeclared for some reason.

Comment: oh yea..sorry I thought you typedefed

Comment: @4386427 Thank you. Do I need to free the memory later?

Comment: @4386427.: Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Allocate `struct`s instead of pointers to `struct`, like this:

```
struct dretva P[5];
//            ^
//     no asterisk
P[0].id=nove[0][2];
//  ^
//  dot in place of ->
```

Currently, you allocate pointers, which are not set to point to actual `struct`s, so reading or writing to them is undefined behavior.